# How to read strings inside parameters

Tags: c++, string

Let's say my program takes a user input and a user decides to input this:
"new('Hi', 'Bye')"

Hi and Bye are just an example, we don't know what the user would actually input.

How would I extract those 2 strings (hi and bye)? I don't understand how to do this. I read more about strings in C++ but I still don't know how to do this.

Comment: Find the (, then see if there's a ' after it, then look for the next ' ? Depends what you actually want to do.

Comment: You might be looking for [regular expressions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex).

Comment: @immibis , I have already done that via the "find" method in std::string, it did not help me sadly

Comment: String parsing is a *huge* topic. It cannot reasonably be answered here unless you provide a *lot* more details about your specific problem to be solved. Some sample code would be good, too. Use the [edit] link to add to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really get two strings from the users input. Even if they format it like

```
"word" "more words" "blah blah blah"
```

...it's still going to be stored in a single string. Whatever you're trying to do, you may want to try asking for the strings separately, or guide the user on how to show where the divider is (suggest a comma maybe).

As for making multiple strings out of what you have, you can always just read through the big string if you know the delimiter (I used a comma) and divide it into two strings, `s1` and `s2`, as so:

```
input = "color, length";
string s1 = "";
string s2 = "";
for (int i=0; i<input.length(); i++)
{
  if(input[i] == ",")
  {
    s1 = input.substr(0, i);
    s2 = input.substr(i+1);
    break;
  }
}
```